# MySQL Optimize Join With Filter and Order On Different Tables

Tags: mysql

The following query is running slowly (over five seconds) with around five million records on in each table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `items`.* 
FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
WHERE `tags`.`name` = '...'
ORDER BY `items`.`stars` DESC LIMIT 64;
```

I'm unclear about the best strategy to index. My initial thought is to add a composite index to `items.id` + `items.stars` and a composite index to `tags.item_id` + `tags.name` - however this hasn't reduced the query time significantly. I have indexes on all foreign keys and an index on `items.stars` and `tags.name`.

`EXPLAIN` shows both my indexes (`index_tags_on_item_id_and_name` and `index_items_on_id_and_stars`) as possible keys but neither is used:

```
1 | SIMPLE | tags  | ref    | index_tags_on_name | 5 | const        | 326538 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2 | SIMPLE | items | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | 4 | tags.item_id | 1      |
```

Any ideas or best practices on how to proceed for a JOIN with a criteria on one side and ORDER on the other? My only thought right now is to replicate the `stars` in the `tags`.

Comment: Are you sure you need `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to select columns of only one table why do you need to join two tables in the first place? instead try subqueries like this:

```
select * from items where id in ( select item_id from tags where tags.name = '...'
 ) order by items.stars desc limit 64
```

not sure if it will improve the performance, but worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange that query to take advantage of your `index(tags.item_id,tags.name)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `items`.* 
FROM `items` WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
       AND `tags`.`name` = '...' ) 
ORDER BY `items`.`stars` DESC LIMIT 64;
```